# C# Change printer driver programmatically

Tags: c#, printing, driver, xps, spool

How can I automate below wizard using C# so that I can install "XPS Class Printer Driver" for my virtual printer.

[image]

I have created a installer by which I have created printer and port but problem is I want to use Microsoft XPS Printer Driver which is not installed on machine. I can install it from above Printer driver wizard but couldn't found a way to automate it via C#.

I know we can use DRIVER_INFO_6 or Management api but don't know how ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft XPS Printer Driver is installed as part of the Windows feature "Microsoft XPS Document Writer".

[Control Panel -> Programs -> Programs and Features -> Windows Features](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdjN9.png)

You can enable this feature programmatically via the command line (with elevated/administrator privileges).

```
dism /online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:Printing-XPSServices-Features
```

Using C# you can run the command using [Process.Start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=net-7.0#system-diagnostics-process-start(system-diagnostics-processstartinfo)). You may need to modify your application's app.config and use runas.exe to achieve elevated privileges necessary for the dism command.